# Call Dataset property in foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I have a data set that that I would like to call in a foreach loop that is a property. I do not want to use .table["xxx"]

```
public DataSet run(string query)
{ 
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
    return dataset;
}

string query = "select * from table";
foreach (DataRow row in  run(query))
{
//
}
```

Comment: Why do you fill a DataSet if you only want to use a DataTable? There is an overload for DataTable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx

Comment: DataSets don't have rows, they have tables. So you need to iterate over the tables first. You also need to declare the DataSet :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataSet doesn't have any method to return DataRow objects.

If you can't specify the TableName returned you can use a numeric Index like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in  run(query).Tables[0].Rows)
{
//
}
```

If your query might return more than one row you should loop thru all tables like so:

```
foreach(DataTable table in run(query).Tables)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `DataTable` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *exactly* what you wanted to avoid: this at least is a numeric index. But that leaves me wondering where your original dataset is declared.

```
foreach (DataRow row in  run(query).Tables[0].Rows)
{
   //
}
```

And just to warn you: your run() method is an anti-pattern. I see a lot of people want to abstract away a database call to a simple method that accepts a string, and they almost always forget one important thing: query parameters. The result is code littered throughout the project that uses string concatenation to build sql in unsafe ways.